# Python - input() not equal to what was expected

Tags: python

I am using python. This is what i'm trying to do:

Ask the user to select the course the student is following using the codes:
CS for GCSE Computer Science
ICT for GCSE ICT
Display the student details on the screen:
If the user entered CS for the course, it should display it as “GCSE Computer Science”, if they entered ICT it should display “GCSE ICT”. If any other data is entered it should display an error message.
Ask the user to confirm the information is correct.
If any information is incorrect, ask the user to re-enter it then display the student details again.
Return to the welcome message.

```
print("Contact Details")
def rep():
    global course
    course = input("Enter CS or ICT")

rep()
if course == "cs":
    print("You have selected GCSE Computer Science")
    correct=input("Is this correct?")
    if course == "yes":
        print("Contact Details")
    else:
        rep()
if course ==  ICT:
    print("You have selected GCSE ICT")
    correct=input("Is this correct?")
    if correct == yes:
    print("Contact Details")
    else:
        rep()

else:
    print("ERROR!!!")
    rep()
```

My error is this:

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\Azad\Documents\Homework\Computer Science\Practise Task         1.py 
Contact Details
Enter CS or ICTCS
ERROR!!!
Enter CS or ICT
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting. Kindly post the entire stack trace.

Comment: `course = 'cs'` you forget quotes for strings

Comment: I vote this as having the worst title ever.

Comment: @PascalvKooten yeah you're right. But then let's teach him/her to use a better title. What that title would be? I thought about it but I've found nothing to fit. Any idea ?

Comment: @EhsanAbd I was on my phone, but something like "input() not equal to what was expected" would be an upgrade, taking into account the person has little knowledge of python to use "more correct" terminology. A title that is so general it could be the title for any python question on here should not be allowed...

Comment: I am sorry I have very little knowledge with python. I have changed the title to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are assigning wrongly to `course` variable. You need to tell that is `global`. I think you want this, right?

```
global course


def rep():
    global course
    course = input("Enter CS or ICT. Enter EXIT to quit... ")

while True:
    print("Welcome message here...")
    rep()

    if course == "EXIT":
        break

    elif course == "CS":
        print("You have selected GCSE Computer Science")

        while True:
            correct=input("Is this correct? ")
            if correct == "yes":
                print("CS Contact Details")
                break

            elif correct == "no":
                break

            else:
                print("Please, type yes or no")

    elif course == "ICT":
        print("You have selected GCSE ICT")

        while True:
            correct=input("Is this correct? ")
            if correct == "yes":
                print("ICT Contact Details")
                break

            elif correct == "no":
                break

            else:
                print("Please, type yes or no")

    else:
        print("ERROR. Please, select CS or ICT")
```

Comment: Only problem is that with your code whatever they type, "yes" or "no" it still  asks them to input CS or ICT, Is it possible to take them back to the title "Contact Details"

Comment: Of course possible. Can you describe what is your use case?

Comment: Ask the user to select the course the student is following using the codes:
CS for GCSE Computer Science
ICT for GCSE ICT
Display the student details on the screen:
If the user entered CS for the course, it should display it as “GCSE Computer Science”, if they entered ICT it should display “GCSE ICT”. If any other data is entered it should display an error message.
Ask the user to confirm the information is correct.
If any information is incorrect, ask the user to re-enter it then display the student details again.
Return to the welcome message.

Comment: @PartyLikeaDragon Like this?

Comment: @Vaaijon Yeah thats what I have have to do

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your help

Comment: You are welcome. For the future: Always, describe what you want to do, provide your code and error. In other case, it is difficult to know what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should place single (`'`) or double (`"`) quotes around `'cs'` and `'ict'` and also other `string`s in your code like 'yes'. You could also use `.lower` to ensure your code works when people enter things like `CS` or `Yes` like this:

```
if course.lower() == 'cs':
    print("You have selected GCSE Computer Science")
```

**By the way please write your error when you're posting in SO.**